# How do I merge values from multiple columns into one in mysql?

Tags: mysql

in my table i have 4 columns

```
Product_id1   Product_id2   Product_id3   Product_id4
2                 4              5           5
3                 2              1           6
```

i want something like this

```
Product_id
2,4,5,5
3,2,1,6
```

cant think of how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use mySQL concat function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(Product_id1,',',Product_id2,',',Product_id3,',',Product_id4) 
   as product_id from table where 1;
```

you can use mysql `concat` function